# How can I remove a Theme from One Shape of Many in Visio 2016

Tags: themes, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, microsoft-office-2016

### The Issue

I have a **Visio 2016** diagram that has a theme, but I want to remove the theme from one object. In Visio 2010 you could do Format > Remove Theme. I'm not seeing any such option in Vision 2016.

### My System

- Visio 2016 Pro
- Developer Mode enabled
- Windows 10

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hidden in the Shape Styles panel on the Home tab of the ribbon.

You'll need to click the expansion button here:
[image]

Then it's the bottom option:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Great graphics also. I will not be able to try it out but it looks accurate, so I'm marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to change the shape in the HOME tab > Editing > Change Shape.  You should be able to see the theme and make changes to it from there.

The option presented worked for containers in my diagram.