# How can I set a theme in a Visio document without resetting existing shapes?

Tags: themes, microsoft-visio

I have a diagram with a number of shapes that I have formatted (colors, font and line styles, etc.) and want to keep the same.

But I would like to set a style for new shapes.  But...

If I add a style to an existing document it changes all my shapes.

If I then use "Remove Style" ([How can I remove a Theme from One Shape of Many in Visio 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1109937/how-can-i-remove-a-theme-from-one-shape-of-many-in-visio-2016)) it removes the styles but does not return my shapes to their previous appearance; instead they are returned to some default values.

How can I add a theme to my existing document without destroying existing formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Select all the shapes (Control-A), the ribbon **Developer** -> **Protection** and select all the Theme protections.

Now go back to the Design tab and select your new theme.

Select all shapes again as above and turn off the protections you added.

New shapes you add will have the new theme but old shapes will keep their previous theme.